# the right way to install openi-kinect

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, openni, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just brought a kinect and wanted to the rgdbslam
I download the SensorKinect-Bin-Linux64-v5.0.1.32.tar.bz2 and installed it.
after that I issued "roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch" and I got the following
error messages

```
enter c[camera/depth/metric_rect-9] process has died [pid 24153, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric /camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=image_rect_raw image:=image_rect __name:=metric_rect __log:=/home/benzene/.ros/log/7b10089a-cf1e-11e2-a66b-001e33286433/camera-depth-metric_rect-9.log].
```

does anyone knows what's going on ?
please teach me how to install the kinect driver in the right way.
thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64479/the-right-way-to-install-openi-kinect/) by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [goetz.marc](https://answers.ros.org/users/4958/goetz.marc/) on 2013-06-06**:
did you try using apt-get? the packages are ros-groovy-openni-camera and ros-groovy-openni-launch, or fuerte respectively

**Comment by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on 2013-06-07**:
yes, I did !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to install the kinect, under Unbuntu 12.04 or 12.10, with ROS-GROOVY follow this procedure :

- install Ubuntu (12.10 or 12.04)
- install ros groovy as following : http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu
- install ros-groovy-openni-* by doing in console "sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-openni-*"
- download olf version of NITE 1.5.2.21 at http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/
- extract zip file in a folder
- extract bz2 file in a folder
- in terminal, go in NITE folder (with command "cd foldername")
- launch UNINSTALL script first, by doing in terminal "sudo ./uninstall.sh"
- launch install script by doing in terminal "sudo ./install.sh"

Have a good day !

Bests,

Stéphane

---

Originally posted by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) with karma: 1304 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on 2013-06-07**:
thanks for your reply, but it didn't work. I got No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-06-07**:
Please specify your setup in your question : distribution, ROS version etc... :-)

**Comment by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on 2013-06-07**:
Thanks for the reply. But I'm using fuerte

**Comment by [KevinNickels](https://answers.ros.org/users/6631/kevinnickels/) on 2013-09-27**:
Agree with lindzey - NITE steps not required (for me).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This worked for me (groovy on Ubuntu 12.04, 64-bit, running in Parallels 8 on OSX 10.8.3)

- Install Ubuntu 12.04
- Install groovy following [these instructions](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu)
- sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-openni-camera
- sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-openni-launch

(This appears to be the same as @Stephane, but w/o the NITE steps)

To check that it worked:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color
```

If you're getting "no devices connected", you may want to see if your computer has detected the kinect. The output of 'lsusb' or 'dmesg' may be helpful. Also - for a ROS-less way of testing your computer's connection with the kinect:

```
sudo apt-get install freenect
freenect-glview
```

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on 2013-06-07**:
Thanks for the reply , but i'm using fuerte.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-06-07**:
The fact that you are using fuerte is anot a probelm, you should just replace the steps of "grovy" with fuerte. Please do a "lsusb", and post us the output (edit your question, and please add also your Ubuntu distrib and the fact you're using fuerte).

**Comment by [Muhannad](https://answers.ros.org/users/8041/muhannad/) on 2013-10-23**:
Hi,

When I do the command sudo apt-get install freenect I get the following error, Can you please help !

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
freenect : Depends: libfreenect-bin but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libfreenect0.1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-10-23**:
You should not post a question inside another question, neither as a comment. Please open a new question for this.
Anyway, please specify your ubuntu version when you will ask :-)